# Solr denormalization and update of referenced data

Tags: solr, lucene, parent-child, elasticsearch, relation

Consider the following situation. We have a database which stores writers and books in two separate tables. One book obviously stores the reference to the writer who wrote the book.
For Solr i have to denormalize this structure into one big document where every book contains the details of the writer associated. This index is now used for querying books.

One user of the system now decides to update a writer record in the system. Because many books can be associated with it i have to update every document in Solr which have embedded data from this writer record. This is very painful because i have to delete and re-add every affected document as far as i know.

Is there any better way of doing this? I need near realtime update of the index in the system if one of the referenced data gets modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a perfect usecase for nested documents. As far as I know lucene does support nested documents but Solr doesn't, not totally sure about the current state of this feature.

This feature is available in elasticsearch though. You might want to have a look at it, there's an article I just wrote that can be interesting if you want to know [what's so cool about elasticsearch](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/09/25/whats-so-cool-about-elasticsearch/) in my opinion. Your question just reminded me that I didn't mention the nested documents feature in my article, which is really cool too. You can use the [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) in your mapping. If you want to know more you can have a look at [this](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/) article. By the way it contains exactly the books/authors example.

Elasticsearch also helps you while [updating documents](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update.html). You don't need to reindex the whole document but send only the changes through a script. Thanks to the fact that it stores the [source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field.html) document that has been indexed it internally retrieves it, updates it running the script and reindexes it. That's how lucene internally works since its index segments are write-once. With Solr 4, which will be soon released, you can [update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139) documents providing only the changes, but as far as I know this works only if all your fields are stored. The fields that are not stored cannot be retrieved from the index.

If we are talking about Near Real Time updates, elasticsearch does use the Lucene Near Real Time API and refreshes automatically the index reader every second. Solr 3 doesn't use yet those APIs but Solr 4 does.

Comment: Thanks, i'll read your blog post later. Nested documents look like something that i need just didn't know it exists. However i still don't know how it speeds up the nested document update process. I have to investigate a little further.

Comment: The goal is to index authors only once and have books only pointing to them instead of actually containing them. This way you'd update each author only once.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'll take ES for a pilot then :)

Comment: How complex this structure can be? The example in the question was the simplest i can think about. In our system records can refer to each other in a very complex way. Even references between books are allowed. Can ES handle that?

Comment: Well, you need to consider that a search engine is not a relational database. You'll need to somehow flatten your data a little. I'd say everything depend on your usecase and the way you want to query your data (taking relations into account).

Answer (score 0):

For updating nested types in SOLR you can use dataimporters and delta imports. The example on https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example shows how this would work. Obviously you would then need to have solr access your database.